# mxnet packages with Rstudio on Virtual machine

Tags: r, linux, azure, cloud, mxnet

I want to install r studio on virtual machine to work with mxnet package.

Here is how to configure Rstudio on microsoft azzure linux virtual machine:
http://moresi.de/posts/2016-04-02-setting-up-r-studio-server-on-microsoft-azure.html

And there is how to install mxnet packages for linux:
https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/get_started/install.html

My question is: If I will install R-studio and Mxnet package following the step in this 2 tutorial will I be able to use mxnet package from R Studio workspace?

Another question is: It is possible to install all availible r packages in this configuration from R studio workspace?

I know that maybe this is a trivial question, but i am completly new to microsoft azzure, and spend a lot of time looking for an answer on web. Its seems that there wasn't any exemple of using mxnet packages with R on cloud.I would be very grateful even for some tips : )

Comment: It should work. I have used mxnet in R on AWS for quite a while.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Yes, you can run mxnet through Rstudio server, I currently do this on my AWS linux instance and login via the browser.

No, you cannot install everything from Rstudio and will have to ssh in and compile/install mxnet and a few other things. Unless you want the CPU mxnet instead of the GPU verion, that might be precompiled. The GPU installation process is a nightmare, I wouldn't recommend unless you have a moderate level of linux experience.

Comment: Though there is a terminal in rstudio now so maybe no need for ssh